# Why would selecting a lot of rows crash my game?

Tags: java, android, sql

I have a databse that contains: 
`id , playlistname , playlistnum`
and I want to get alll the rows where `playlistname = "CoolPlaylist"`
and I want to parse them 1 by 1, so I thought of doing this:

```
String name = "CoolPlaylist"; 
String[] columns = String[] {id , playlistname , playlistnum};
Cursor c = myDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, key_playlistname +"="+name,
                            null, null, null, null);
```

but when I do this, the code crashes. Does somebody know what the problem probably is?

Comment: I guessing it's something to do with those nulls. You need to debug the program. *Read* the error message, they're typically very helpful. Use the debugger, step through the code, ensure your values are set the way you expect them to be set.

Answer (score 1):

This portion of your code

```
key_playlistname +"="+name
```

probably needs the name part in quotes

i.e.

```
key_playlistname + "= '" + name + "'"
```

Otherwise CoolPlayList probably be treated as an SQL command and would come back with an error such as invalid SQL statement.